# Windows Azure - Caching - How to get all cache items

Tags: caching, azure, azure-caching

I used the following method in asp.net to retrieve all caches (then I remove some caches based on the regular expression pattern).

```
IDictionaryEnumerator caches = HttpContext.Current.Cache.GetEnumerator();
```

I found GetObjects* but they are only available in Windows Sever AppFabric.

Is there any equivalent in Windows Azure AppFabric Caching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its current manifestation, [no](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185678.aspx).
You will need to know which keys there are/you need to get and set appropriate timeouts if you don't want to keep track of your cache items.
Also missing are regions, tags and notifications which (for many use-cases) would offer a perfect workaround/efficient alternative to getting all cache-items or keys.

If you are unhappy with the state of azure caching you could put your frustration [here](http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/40626-windows-azure-appfabric-feature-voting/suggestions/1810245-add-tags-notifications-regions-to-azure-cache-so) or [there](http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/2214571-cache-needs-work).

Answer (score 1):

With latest release of Windows Azure Caching (Preview) along with Windows Azure SDK 1.7, you have all the features that were available in on-premise Windows AppFabric Caching product.

Such as: Notifications, Regions, Tags, High Availability, etc.

The Windows Azure Caching (preview) does not have any extra cost other than the compute cost.

Please look into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914153.aspx for more details.

Comment: Olnrao, I used Azure Caching (Preview) since the day it come out. ;) It has all the features like big brother Windows Server AppFabric. Thank you for your answer!